# Optimizing a query

Tags: mysql

I have a query that selects any information from a db. This information I will use for defining the article price. The problem is that the query takes 3 seconds to execute. This time must to be multiply for many article.

How can I optimize this query? In the articoli table there are 16 330 rows.

This is the query

```
SELECT ts_scon, AI_CODICIVA, 
       AI_LIS_EURO1, AI_LIS_EURO2, 
       AI_LIS_EURO3, AI_LIS_EURO4, 
       AI_LIS_EURO5, cl_tipocl
  FROM tabscon, articoli, clienti
 WHERE ts_azienda = 'SRL' 
   AND AI_AZIENDA = 'SRL'
   AND AI_CODIREST = $cod_articolo 
   AND cl_azienda = 'SRL' 
   AND cl_codice = $cod_cliente
   AND ts_codice IN (
        SELECT cl_tabsco 
          FROM clienti 
         WHERE cl_codice = $cod_cliente 
           AND CL_AZIENDA = 'SRL')
   AND ts_grusco IN (
        SELECT ai_grupscon 
          FROM articoli 
         WHERE ai_codirest = $cod_articolo  
           AND AI_AZIENDA = 'SRL')
```

---

This is the EXPLAIN result. The results are the same with indices that without indices.

> id|select_type|table|type|possible_keys|key|key_len|ref|rows|Extra
>   1|PRIMARY|clienti|const|PRIMARY|PRIMARY|25|const,const|1
>   1|PRIMARY|tabscon|ref|PRIMARY,azie_grsco_codice|PRIMARY|15|const|505|Using where
>   1|PRIMARY|articoli|ALL|PRIMARY,barcodeidx,StatoAidx,Statoidx|NULL|NULL|NULL|16333|Using where; Using join buffer
>   3|DEPENDENT SUBQUERY|articoli|ref|PRIMARY,barcodeidx,StatoAidx,Statoidx StatoAidx|15|const|7311|Using where
>   2|DEPENDENT|SUBQUERY|clienti|const|PRIMARY

Sorry for the little order but not yet practical.

Comment: run the query whit `DESCRIBE` infront of it, and show us the output

Comment: Can you post the output of EXPLAIN as well?

Comment: a `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` for the 3 tables: tabscon, articoli and clienti whould be nice to

Comment: @Puggan Se @ Chris Henry, thanks for your responses, today when i go at work post the result with EXPLAIN infront of the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query-wise the best way to do this would be.

```
SELECT ts_scon, a.AI_CODICIVA, 
  a.AI_LIS_EURO1, a.AI_LIS_EURO2, 
  a.AI_LIS_EURO3, a.AI_LIS_EURO4, 
  a.AI_LIS_EURO5, c.cl_tipocl
FROM tabscon t
JOIN articoli a ON ts_azienda = ai_azienda
JOIN articoli a2 ON ts_azienda = a2.ai_azienda AND a2.ai_codirest = $cod_articolo AND a2.ai_grusco = ts_grusco
JOIN clienti c ON ai_azienda = cl_azienda
JOIN clienti c2 ON ai_azienda = c2.cl_azienda AND c2.cl_codice = $cod_cliente AND c2.cl_tabsco = ts_codice
WHERE ts_azienda = 'SRL' 
AND AI_CODIREST = $cod_articolo
```

That said, I'm not sure exactly what information you're trying to get here; you may not need to join onto those tables twice, but without understanding the data I can't be sure.

Answer (score 0):

You're definitely going to need some indexes if you don't have them already. Without knowing your application, it's guesswork to figure out exactly where the indexes will be helpful.  That being said, try putting indexes on

```
articoli.ai_azienda
articoli.ai_codirest

tabscon.ts_azienda
tabscon.ts_codice

clienti.cl_azienda
clienti.cl_codice
```

Use the EXPLAIN command before you add these indexes, then add them one by one and use EXPLAIN again, to see which ones actually make a difference.

Also, it seems that your query returns results for individual values of $cod_articolo and $cod_clienti.  If your business logic works that way, you might try to work your query so it returns all the articles for a particular $cod_clienti. The query still might take a while, but it would return a whole lot of rows rather than just the one.

Comment: I'll try with the indexes and post the EXPLAIN results...thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved so

```
SELECT ts_scon, AI_CODICIVA, AI_LIS_EURO1, AI_LIS_EURO2, AI_LIS_EURO3, AI_LIS_EURO4, AI_LIS_EURO5, cl_tipocl
FROM tabscon ts JOIN articoli a ON ts.ts_grusco = a.ai_grupscon, clienti
WHERE ts_azienda = 'SRL' AND AI_AZIENDA = 'SRL' AND AI_CODIREST = $cod_articolo AND cl_azienda = 'SRL' AND cl_codice = 1128
AND ts_codice IN (SELECT cl_tabsco FROM clienti WHERE cl_codice = 1128 AND CL_AZIENDA = 'SRL')
```

Comment: "x IN (*subquery*)" is a *really* inefficient way of performing a query, because the subquery will be executed for every potential row that might be returned. You should change this to use a JOIN, like in my answer.